# The font Calibri is missing. Your text might look different with Pages, Numbers

Tags: ios, pages, numbers

My documents **do not** contain that font anywhere. But the iPad still complains about this. How can I remove completely these font from document? Is there a way to do this? Maybe there are special invisible chars with that font?

Comment: I'd just ignore it. You could Select All, and change the font.

Comment: no, select all and changing font didnt help.